# PowerMockito Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory() returns null

Tags: android, robolectric, powermockito

I'm having problems mocking `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()` with PowerMockito

Gradle

```
testImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:2.0.5'
testImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito2:2.0.4'
testImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-classloading-xstream:2.0.4'
testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:3.1.0'
```

Test class

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({Environment.class})
public class StorageUtilsTest {
    @Test
    public void UseExternalStoragePublicDirectoryWhenItIsAvailable() {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(Environment.class);
        File mockStorageDirectoryFile = Mockito.mock(File.class);
        File aFile = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);
        PowerMockito.when(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM)).thenReturn(mockStorageDirectoryFile);
    }
}
```

`aFile` is null so the `when` returns a mock exception

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.NotAMockException: Argument should be a mock, but is: class java.lang.Class
```

Seems the problem is with the `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()` method returning `null`

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: On Android Q???

Comment: Yes it is using android Q

Comment: Then that is the reason.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Though my target app is using API 29, I have to provide support through API 19.  So how to do that in the test?  The code has API dependent coding and thus uses getExternalStoragePublicDirectory() for versions less than API 29 and above API 19.